# How can I create a 3D view of a grayscale depth map?

Tags: opengl

I've got a grayscale depth bmp image. 
How can I create a 3D model of it?
In addition I've got a color bmp of the exact same image, which I would like to use as a texture for the model above.

I was thinking about creating GL_QUADS and assign texture to each vertex, but I'm not sure which coordinates to use for the vertexes and textures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a regular grid in the xy plane, one vertex per pixel, with texture coordinates going from 0 to 1, then set the z value of each vertex to the grayscale value (you probably want to scale it by a constant factor). The vertex coordinates don't really matter, as long as they form a regular grid.

Comment: If I'll use GL_POINTS to draw the different pixels' vertexes, will I be able to rotate it?

Comment: Disregard the comment, I was able to rotate it.

Comment: I am trying to achieve similar effect with no results; I am using GL_QUADS as primitive and I generated a regular grid of xy points and set z as the corresponding rayscale value; however I am trying to apply a texture given by a 2-d image. Any recommendation?

Comment: @FranciscoCunha You mean you have an additional texture that you want to map onto a mesh created from a depth map image? That would be beyond the scope of this question. There are tons of tutorials on general texture mapping.